# PaperTrail not updating the meta fields when update model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paper-trail-gem

I'm using paper_trail in my rails app. I'm defining a `:meta` to store some data for each model. Inside that meta there is an attribute `:date` that takes the value of the date on the model. Now when i create a new record for a model it stores in the `versions` table the data correctly, but if I modify that record when I save it, it also create a new record in versions for the event update, but the date attribute is not modified in the versions table even when that attribute was modified on the model.

How can i modify the config for paper_trail so that the attribute is modified when the model modifies it?

```ruby
has_paper_trail class_name: 'HistoryElement',
  on: [:create, :update, :destroy],
  meta: {
    patient_id: :patient_id, 
    instance_id: :instance_id, 
    status: :status, 
    date: :inicio, 
    item_type_id: HistoryElement::EVENT_TYPES[:dialysis_session]
  }
```

Comment: Looking at the code provided so far, I don't see anything wrong. If you can reproduce this using [this script](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/blob/master/.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/bug_report.md) then you may have found a bug. We are temporarily not accepting issues, but if you can reproduce this using the script, please open a PR.

Comment: @JaredBeck: I got the same issue today. I noticed the meta value is 1 step behind the current state of the record.

Comment: @GiangNguyen i had to pull the gem code and modify it for my needs and point the app to that gem code insteed of the public one. The gem is not updating the data with the new data, as you say it stay 1 step behind

Answer (score 1):

PaperTrail version persists the previous state, not the new state of the record, so this is intended behavior. You can use proc to retrieve fresh data (or just any data PaperTrail would omit) from the record

```
meta: {
  date: proc { |record| record.date }
}
```

Comment: For posterity, i was experiencing a similar problem with API and session controller not storing the user. This solved it!